# Django. Как скрыть ненужные поля в форме в зависимости от выбранной категории?

Tags: javascript, django

Все привет. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении нового объявления, выбирая категорию, скрывались ненужные поля в форме. Понимаю, что это делается чере JS, но я пока плохо разбираюсь, поэтому прошу подсказать, если кто хорошо разбирается.
Например, я хочу, чтобы при выборе "Дома и участки" исчезал "Этаж":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя главная модель:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Риелтор')
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
  region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Область')
  city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Город')
  district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Район')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
  landmark = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Ориентир')
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
  stage = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Этаж')
  rooms = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Количество комнат')
```

forms.py:

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = ('realtor',)
```

Форма в шаблоне:

```
<form method="POST"  novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% bootstrap_form form %}
   <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
</form>
```

Посмотрел в браузере структуру формы в шаблоне:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_category">Категория</label>
<select name="category" class="form-control" title="" required id="id_category">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="1">Квартиры</option>
  <option value="2">Коммерческое</option>
  <option value="3">Дома и участки</option>
</select></div>
```

Структура поля, которое я хочу скрыть:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_stage">Этаж</label>
<input type="number" name="stage" value="0" 
class="form-control" placeholder="Этаж" title="" id="id_stage">
</div>
```

Попробовал сделать так, но пока не работает:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#id_category').change(function () {
      var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
      var valueSelected = $(this).val();

      if (valueSelected === 3){
          $('#id_rooms').hide();
      } else {
          $('#id_rooms').show();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Если знаете, подскажите, пожалуйста, или пример какой, как это делается. Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Главная проблема в том, что вы сравниваете значение с целым числом, а нужно со строкой. Также добавил **id** (*id_rooms*) в `div`, который нужно скрыть.

```js
$('#id_category').change(function () {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = $(this).val();

  if (valueSelected === '3'){
      $('#id_rooms').hide();
  } else {
      $('#id_rooms').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_category">Категория</label>
  <select name="category" class="form-control" title="" required id="id_category">
    <option value="" selected>---------</option>
    <option value="1">Квартиры</option>
    <option value="2">Коммерческое</option>
    <option value="3">Дома и участки</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="id_rooms">
  <label for="id_stage">Этаж</label>
  <input type="number" name="stage" value="0" 
  class="form-control" placeholder="Этаж" title="" id="id_stage">
</div>
```

Comment: Всё работает, но т.к. это бутстрап форма, не получается скрыть Слово Этаж, поле, а слово Этаж остается. Как тогда быть? Вверху то это я в браузере код взял, в шаблоне то уменя просто прописано, что это бутстрап форма.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Перефразируйте вопрос. Не важно, что там бутстрап, я думаю. Вы ведь хтмл разметку видите.

Answer (score 0):

> Всё работает, но т.к. это бутстрап форма, не получается скрыть Слово Этаж, поле, а слово >Этаж остается. Как тогда быть?

Возможно, не актуально, но, так как я тоже же с этим столкнулся, отвечу, вдруг кому поможет.
Действия всё те же, что и выше. В данном случае:

```
$('label[for="id_stage"]').hide();
```